# How does memory leakage occur in C?

Tags: c, memory-leaks, dynamic-memory-allocation

I'm having a bit of difficulty trying to visualize how leakage occurs. We're given this code and it can be compiled and run but it leaks memory. "How does the program leak memory? Draw and explain."

```
#include <stdlib.h>

struct nod {
    char name[30];
    int tel;
    struct nod * next;
    struct nod * prev;
};
typedef struct nod Nod;

int main() {
    Nod * p =  malloc(sizeof(Nod));
    p -> next =  malloc(sizeof(Nod));
    p -> next -> prev = p;
    free(p);
}
```

Comment: Count the number of calls to `malloc` and to `free` and compare.

Comment: If you know how to draw a linked list with pen and paper, you can do this task. If you don't know how to draw a linked list, or even what a linked list is, you cannot complete the task. In either case it is _your_ homework, make an effort of solving it yourself before posting here.

Comment: @Lundin , I'm familiar with linked lists since before, and do know that they mean (in Python context, I know the concept of data structures are basically exactly the same in other languages as well). It's just that C is a new programming language for me and I hadn't really understood exacly how to malloc and free functions work in conjunction with each other. Thank you for your comments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
    Nod * p =  malloc(sizeof(Nod));
    p -> next =  malloc(sizeof(Nod));
    p -> next -> prev = p;
    free(p);
```

When `p` is freed, the reference `p->next` is lost. So the program cannot `free` the allocated memory by `p -> next =  malloc(sizeof(Nod));`.

In reality, the program will not be able to release the memory. If this happen often, the memory used by the process will slowly increase. If the process use too much memory, the system will start to `swap` and the computer performances will decrease significantly.

The program `valgrind` can help you to detect memory leaks.

Comment: If the OS swaps or not is OS dependent. Depending on the OS, this particular program may not even leaking, as some OSes will clean up the memory anyway, after the process exited.

Comment: Yes this is correct. And on embedded systems without OS, it might also crash. My comment regarding swapping is just an example.

Comment: Thank you @Robert! It was just a bit hard to wrap my head around it since it is a new language for me so I didn't really understand what happened, since the visualization http://pythontutor.com/c.html#mode=display didn't really show the leakage.

Comment: In most hosted systems there probably won't be any memory allocated in the first place, since the actual memory area isn't touched by the program. But that's another story.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using recent versions of the GCC compilers, You can use the sanitize flags to detect memory leaks

```
gcc test.c -o test -fsanitize=address -fno-omit-frame-pointer
```

When you run the program, you get an output like

```
=================================================================
==2356059==ERROR: LeakSanitizer: detected memory leaks

Direct leak of 56 byte(s) in 1 object(s) allocated from:
#0 0x7fad5bc6b459 in __interceptor_malloc /build/gcc/src/gcc/libsanitizer/asan/asan_malloc_linux.cpp:145
#1 0x55b353e65198 in main (/home/xxx/xxx/test+0x1198)
#2 0x7fad5ba18151 in __libc_start_main (/usr/lib/libc.so.6+0x28151)

SUMMARY: AddressSanitizer: 56 byte(s) leaked in 1 allocation(s).
```

Comment: Thank you!  It was one the instructions as well to try with -fsanitize. It worked!